# How to remove menu bar

Tags: gnome, 11.10

How can I remove one of the menu bars on the desktop in classical mode? I just updated to Ubuntu 11.10, logged in with the classic Gui, and I cannot right click on the menu bars.

Comment: What do you mean "classical mode" and why would you want to right click on the menu bar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean the panels: Use Alt+Rightclick instead of just Rightclick. See [this blog post from Vincent Untz](http://www.vuntz.net/journal/post/2011/04/13/gnome-panel-is-dead,-long-live-gnome-panel!) for some more about the Gnome3 Gnome-Panel.