# Modifying the Gnome Classic panel

Tags: 12.04, panel

How can I modify the panel (in classic Gnome mode) such as adding items, moving, etc. in Ubuntu 12.04?

I had the same problem with an earlier version of Ubuntu [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66478/), which received an answer to press Alt while right clicking, and it worked for that version, but this does not seem to work for 12.04.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/126300/how-do-i-configure-the-gnome-panel-from-a-script

Comment: @StephenMyall I am not asking how to do it from command. I am asking how to do it from GUI.

Answer (score 3):

The following keyboard combination worked for me on Ubuntu 12.04:
<kbd>Super</kbd>(Button with windows logo on it)+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+Right Mouse Click.

Comment: You are wrong. The user has said that your method work for a previous version, no for Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: The answer was in fact quite correct for some items.  Note that it included the use of the "Windows" Super-key.  With 12.04, and for keyboards that have this button available, one can, for example, use the keyboard short-cut, Super (Windows) key – Alt – Right-click, to add a Shut Down icon to the panel.

Comment: @Lucio If you read his post you will notice he was not including the "Super" key.

I'm not sure if this matters but I used the Gnome 3 repositority when installing Gnome and it works for my installation of Ubuntu 12.04 when using the Gnome Classic interface.

Comment: Well, that could explain way it work for you. Also is good that you have mentioned that this information comes from your own experience. +1 for that ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'll try and help you here - do you mean graphically like with the alacarte menu editor?
It's really straightforward to use.

You access this tool by right clicking the menu area (upper left) in GNOME and selecting “Edit Menus”. When you do this the menu editor will open.

I have not figured out how to post pictures yet, so if you do not come right, lemme know.

Hope this helps

Comment: What you suggest helps editing the menu, but what I want is to modify the bar itself. For example, I want to add the window selectors on the top bar, remove the bottom bar, replace the item that says "Applications" and "Places" with one that integrates them all and simply have the Ubntu logo. I also want to add a system monitor to the top bar that indicates the CPU activity, HDD activity, and s on. There is also indicator that tells the temperatures of the CPU and HDD. I was able to do this with previous versions of Ubuntu.